# Changing Background Color in C++ Game

Tags: c++, colors, background

I'm working on programming a game that involves a start menu on a yellow background. However, I'm having some trouble figuring out how to accomplish this. I'm programming in a Visual Studios Visual C++ environment using a Console Application if that makes a difference. Can anyone tell me how I might create a yellow background for my menu?

Comment: `system("color e0")`?

Comment: Thanks, this worked! If you want to submit it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it so you get credit for it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `system` function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) to set the `COLOR` (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490882.aspx) of the command line to a bright yellow background `E` with dark text `0`:

`system("color e0")`